# LookupAccountSid() corrupts memory heap

Tags: windows, winapi, sid

I spent few days chasing a crash that manifests as structured exception `0xC0000374` (heap corruption)... Of course, reproducible only in customer environment.

Narrowed it down to this (very simplified) code:

```
    DWORD cchName = 0, cchDomain = 0;
    SID_NAME_USE type;
    if (!LookupAccountSidW(NULL, pSid, NULL, &cchName, NULL, &cchDomain, &type))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            <bail via exception or return>;
    }

    cout << cchName << ":" << cchDomain << " -> ";

    DWORD cchName1 = (cchName + 1), cchDomain1 = (cchDomain + 1);

    LPWSTR pName   = ... allocate cchName1   WCHARs ...;
    LPWSTR pDomain = ... allocate cchDomain1 WCHARs ...;

    if (!LookupAccountSidW(NULL, pSid, pName, &cchName1, pDomain, &cchDomain1, &type))
        <bail via exception or return>;

    cout << cchName1 << ":" << cchDomain1 << endl;

    ... deallocate pDomain; // <- here Application Verifier detects corrupted block
    ... deallocate pName;
```

Please, ignore possibility of memory leak (code is simplified). Also, note that according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw) over-allocating by 1 symbol is not necessary. But let me describe what I see in debugger...

For all (but one) SIDs encountered it prints out things like `16:7 -> 15:6` or `6:7 -> 5:6` and everything is dandy. Basically, first call returns required buffer sizes (including terminating `NUL`), second one returns number of symbols written (excluding `NUL`) into provided buffers (which are over-allocated by 1, btw).

Now, one specific SID results in `6:3 -> 5:2` output. But when I look at `pDomain` buffer (which is 4 symbols long) I see truncated domain name `ABCD` (actual domain name is 6 symbols) followed by `NUL` (which corrupts heap control structures). So `LookupAccountSidW` claims it has written only 2(+1) symbols, while in reality is has written 4(+1) symbols into a buffer that is 4 symbols long.

From my standpoint it is a clear bug in `LookupAccountSidW`, but I would really like to figure out how that SID differ from others. Maybe it was migrated from another (shorter) domain?

P.S. It is Windows 10 (10.0.14393.2969)

P.P.S. SID is `S-1-5-21-<3-part domain id>-<user id>`

Comment: You don't need your `cchName1`/`cchDomain1` variables at all. If you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw), when `LookupAccountSid()` fails with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, the returned sizes **include** the null terminator, so you don't need to +1 them manually. Just allocate exactly what `LookupAccountSid()` asked you for.

Comment: the fact that I overallocated by 1 symbol should not cause buffer overruns

Comment: in fact, to get customer over that hump I had to make a special build that over-allocates by 4... anything smaller leads to buffer overrun in `LookupAccountSid`

Comment: The `LookupAccount...()` functions have been around a LONG LONG time, I seriously doubt they have a buffer overflow bug in them. The more likely culprit is misusing the buffers you allocate.  Can you please provide a [mcve] that actually compiles?

Comment: as side note - much more better use `LsaLookupSids` instead `LookupAccountSid` - this api allocate buffers for you. so use it more efficient and more simply. and it can lookup several sids in single call - this is also frequently need

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't provide reproducible example -- it only reproduces in that particular environment with one particular SID. Code is very simple. And buffer overrun is obvious in debugger -- one step (second `LookupAccountSid` call) and boom -- one extra byte after buffer's end is zeroed out. That SID is weird -- that particular user is not recognized by domain controller and yet on that system you could see some details (full name/etc). No idea where that OS gets these details. In any case -- that SID triggers some bug in good old `LookupAccountSid` that "have been around a LONG LONG time".

Comment: @C.M. I don't need the actual SID itself, just *compilable* code, which is part of what a [mcve] is.  For instance, don't leave out the parts that "allocate" and "deallocate" the buffers you are using.

Comment: @RbMm `LsaLookupSids` doesn't return domain name. I need to enumerate domains somehow and pass them to `LsaLookupSids`. Any idea how `LookupAccountSid` figures out domain name from SID? (with `lpSystemName` being NULL)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Originally allocation was made with `malloc(sizeof(WCHAR)*cchName)`. Later I changed it to `GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, ...)` -- it didn't change anything, heap was corrupted in both cases, only time it got discovered changed. Trust me, I know how to deal with memory allocation (20+ years of full-time C++ programming).

Comment: @RemyLebeau ...the fact that `cchDomain` is 3 after first call is very weird -- according to customer they have never had 2-symbol domains ever.

Comment: What does [PsGetSid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psgetsid) show you for that SID? It imports `LookupAccountSidA` so presumably uses this API as well.

Comment: @C.M. - `LsaLookupSids` - return domain name of course. `LookupAccountSid` is only very bad shell over `LsaLookupSids`

Comment: @C.M. - *need to enumerate domains somehow and pass them to LsaLookupSids* - this is absolute false. domains - out parameter. not in. how i say the `LookupAccountSid` internally call `LsaLookupSids`. but this api very bad design. it free already allocated memory, ask you allocate memory itself, copy data to your memory, can query only single sid per call

Comment: @RbMm yes, you are correct, I misread that page.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'll try PsGetSid, but all this happens in customer's environment -- they may simply not let me do that.

Comment: @C.M. I am seeing a similar issue, resulting in a heap corruption after the second call. In the environment that I'm investigating, the SID in question is part of a user's SID history as the associated account was part of a domain migration or two. Testing is difficult, because I have to go through two layers of support to get code run on the environment. Where are you on your search?

Comment: @MichaelMueller I no longer have any access to environment where it could be reproduced. My solution was to allocate minimum 128 bytes for domain and account names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this issue, so I'm documenting my findings for whoever has the misfortune to fall into this trap.

It appears that there is a case where LookupAccountSidA will cause a heap overrun in certain environments.

It is possible to migrate users from one domain to another. The SIDs can remain as part of the domain for historical reasons. LookupAccountSidA is supposed to support looking up these SIDs, and it does so, except that it will overrun the heap internally, when the name of the old domain is longer than the new one.

Under the hood, LookupAccountSidA calls LsaLookupSids2 which gets a PLSA_TRANSLATED_NAME (the names array) and a PLSA_REFERENCED_DOMAIN_LIST. The issue here is that LookupAccountSidA makes use of the wrong array position in order to set up the size required for the domain data. If memory serves, it uses position zero where it should be something other than that. So, if the domain in position zero has a name shorter than the one associated with the SID you're looking up, LookupAccountSidA will overwrite the heap, all on its own.

The only work-around is to pass two buffers of 256 chars, and fill-initialize them to '\0'. Pass these in for your name and domain arrays, and do not trust the size that is returned for the domain. Copy these out of the buffers you get back, and careful not to overrun your buffers on read.

The better option, of course, is to use LsaLookupSids2 and do Unicode-to-multibyte conversion if necessary.

PS: A representative from Microsoft told me that this was a bug that was introduced between Windows 7 and 8. I don't know whether or not this affects LookupAccountSidW, but it most certainly is possible.

Comment: ... but but "The LookupAccount...() functions have been around a LONG LONG time"!!!! LOL Thank you, Michael.

Comment: it does affect `LookupAccountSidW`, my app is Unicode

Comment: I figured it would, since the ANSI methods call into the wide versions under the hood. I just didn't want to mis-represent the raw data by jumping to that conclusion.